# VB6 not responding when interacting with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-express

I have no experience with VB6 and I have ran into error when I run the application with this code included:

```
 Data9.RecordSource = "select * from zag_d where tip=" & tip
 Data9.Refresh

 Data1.RecordSource = "Select distinct god,broj,partner,interno from zag_d where tip=" & tip
 Data1.Refresh
```

VB6 and Application that I'm runing from VB6 goes "not responding". How can i debug it? This is the first time that VB6 is not giving me any debug information, it just stops working.

Comment: a few questions: which database are you using? are you sure your database isn't locking the table due to a pending commit?

Comment: I am using SQL 2008/express. I'm sure that there is no pending commits. I have figured out one thing now.
If i pass the connection parameters: `data9.Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=192.168.5.232\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mpnew;Uid=sa;Pwd=password123;` application and VB6 hang. but if i do not pass parameters and i type in username and password in window that appears, everything gets loaded. The weird thing is: passing connection parameter goes well for all datasources before data9 but only those 2 data above hang application if connection string is passed in .connect @JimJones

Comment: I do remember having similar issues with vb6 and it was always either a wrong SQL Server connection driver / wrong connection string or pending commits in the database. Thanks to your post I have now a nostalgic feeling: I used to teach VB5 and VB6 around 1999.. golden times! :-) Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help. data9.refresh hangs my application. Well, I guess i'll keep on trying different stuff untill it works :) @JimJones

Comment: If `tip` is a string then you should add ' before and after the tip `Data9.RecordSource = "select * from zag_d where tip= ' " & tip & "' "`

Comment: How many records will be returned by the query?  If there are a _lot_ of records (and/or you have a slow connection), then you're just not allowing enough time to download and display the records. You can run SQL Profiler to determine what is occurring to your query (whether it's being blocked, consuming a lot of resources, how long it is running, etc).

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but I believe SQL 2008 was version 10. I don't know if just changing 11.0 to 10.0 is enough. It almost has to be a problem with the connection string. Something like, `Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;`